# Installing xarray_spatial - UnsatisfiableError - But there are no incompatible specifications displayed

Tags: python, geospatial, python-xarray

I am trying to install xarray-spatial using anaconda. I am getting an UnsatisfiableError, but there are no deatils of any incompatible specifications.

Running the following command:

```
(geo_env) C:\Users\Alex>conda install -c conda-forge xarray-spatial
```

Here are the details of the error:

```
(geo_env) C:\Users\Alex>conda install -c conda-forge xarray-spatial
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

Comment: Is that the whole output? And it looks like you may be using a strict channel priority. Have you tried relaxing it? What conda variant are you using?

Comment: Yes that is the whole output. I tried with a flexible channel priority with the same result. Using conda version: 22.11.0, and build version 3.22.0. When I create a new environment I can install the package without an error.

Comment: you likely had a channel conflict. mixing and matching channels in conda can create incompatibility problems. I'd recommend deleting anaconda, which installs a ton of packages into your base environment using the `defaults` channel, and using [`miniforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) or `mambaforge`, which use the `conda-forge` channel as the default.